# When I run "npm start" I get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" on a normal Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, syntax-error

I have tried npm update, npm start then install, but the error seems oddly at the beginning of loading the app itself.

How could it not recognize "import", the very first word of the normal standard bootstrapping file?

The stacktrace is:

```
C:\Users\Andreas\Project>npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Andreas\Project
> node ./app/main.ts

C:\Users\Andreas\Project\app\main.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `node ./app/main.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'node ./app/main.ts'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./app/main.ts
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andreas\Project\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\Andreas\Project>npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Andreas\Project
> node ./app/main.ts

C:\Users\Andreas\Project\app\main.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `node ./app/main.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'node ./app/main.ts'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./app/main.ts
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andreas\Project\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: You're trying to start the angular main.ts file, that is supposed to be transpiled to JavaScript, bundled, downloaded by the browser, and executed by the browser, with node (which is a server-side JavaScript execution environment). That doesn't make sense. Where did you read that you needed to execute this command?

Comment: To run a local debug version, you run "npm start" inside your project? This should start the server? I read it here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

Comment: Here's how your package.json file should look like if you followed the instructions: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json. I guess it doesn't look like that.

Comment: Everything is changed with a new update or something!

The structure of an Angular project has put the app into a src directory. This is all new!

I am restructuring now to figure it out.

Comment: Note that this quickstart structure, as documented, is just a quick start to start developing, and is not intended to be used for real apps that should go to production. You should consider using the angular cli: https://cli.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

Angular has updated its structure, so now, many things are inside a "src" directory.

This made npm confused, so I had to restructure, based on the updated "quickstart project"'s new structure. Some migtration was required, but basically I just moved code files into their proper places.

It was a sucky process, with a sucky error message to instruct. But I guess Angular 2 is pretty ok, and the better structure doesn't hurt.